# Clone a Linux virtual container as a virtual machine for testing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, clone

I have been given one Linux virtual container where I have installed all the apps, databases, etc. Now I want to clone that in my local computer as a virtual machine for testing. The Linux container is using Docker for deployment of containers.

Is there any way I can get a complete clone of the system from inside of it. I have root privileges.

Comment: Is there a reason to clone it from inside, rather than copying / cloning the virtual container?

Comment: @Slartibartfast i dont have permission for that. i ahve to submit the request and it will take week or so to process that